# PHP PDO mysql_data_seek

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm converting some code to access a database to PDO. I've come across the following:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
$row0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And from my readings on Google etc, I understand this should be:

```
$row0 = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, 0);
```

however this isn't working. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where's `$result` coming from?

Comment: $result   = $db->query($someSqlQuery) or die("failed!");  
$someArray = array();  

 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
 array_push($someArray, $row['FirstName']);
        }

Comment: I'm sorry about that formatting, I'm new to SO and need to learn the tags to format code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From manual;

> Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object. The fetch_style parameter determines how PDO returns the row.

You need a `stmt` that was created by `PDO::prepare` method.

Let's see this;

```
// assuming $pdo was created before as well
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
// exec here
$sth->execute();
// get a row here
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// here probably you'll get a print out like
// Array([name] => Banana, [color] => Yellow)
print_r($row);
```

See more details here: [PHP PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: you need to execute a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

First option with query:

You can iterate `query` result directly..

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Second option with execute:

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // fetch the next row from statement
echo $row['FirstName'];
```

Comment: I got - it appeared that the $result = $dbM->query($sqlQuery) 'is cleaned' after a while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)). By writing another $result2 i used that and it worked.